# python regex inserting a space between punctuation and letters

Tags: python, regex, string

I assume the best way to do this is with regex but I do not know how to do it. I am trying to parse a string and put a space between letters and punctuation only. I want to keep punctuation marks together.  As an example if I have the string

"yes!!!"

I want to end up with

"yes", "!!!".

If I have the string

!!!N00bs,

I want to end up with

"!!!", "N00bs"

Is this possible? What is the best way to do this? Right now I am parsing each letter and it a silly way of doing it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know you said you just wanted to strip out punctuation, but just in case you wanted to do that and also wanted to strip out other non-alphanumeric characters in one go such as (@#$%^&*(()<>+=) or whatever, you can just use `\w` and `\W`. It's quite nice. If you're using Python 3.x it'll automatically do the Unicode characters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

something like this:

```
txt = re.sub( r'([a-zA-Z])([,.!])', r'\1 \2', '!!!this, .is, .a .test!!!' )
```

you can switch the order for the other direction

```
re.sub( r'([,.!])([a-zA-Z])', r'\1 \2', txt )
```

probably you can also make it work in one regex as well

Comment: This is almost there. it does not seem to work if the punctuation mark is leading as in what you had before you changed it "!is". I am trying to get a space between punctuation marks and alpha characters

Comment: i changed it because i did not know if you want that case. i will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is totally on me for not being explicit.

Comment: How would you modify this if you wanted to ignore certain formats such "e.g." or other abbreviations?

Comment: Interested in knowing if there is any solution for the problem @donkey asked

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add a space maybe use replace?

```
x = x.replace('!',' ')
```

You may have to use more replace's to remove spaces between punctuation and punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
(.+)\b(.+)
```

It works for both `yes!!!` and `!!!N00bs`

**Explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:(.+)\b(.+))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .+                       any character except \n (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```