# Python: How can I use a regex to split sentences to new lines, and then separate punctuation from words using whitespace?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following input:

```
input = "I love programming with Python-3.3! Do you? It's great... I give it a 10/10. It's free-to-use, no $$$ involved!"
```

First, every sentence should be moved to a new line. Then, all of the punctuation should be separated from the words EXCEPT for "/", " ' ", "-", "+" and "$".

So the output should be:

```
"I love programming with Python-3 . 3 ! 
Do you ?  
It's great . . . 
I give it a 10/10 . 
It's free-to-use , no $$$ involved !"
```

I used the following code:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"([\w/'+$\s-]+|[^\w/'+$\s-]+)\s*", r"\1 ", input)
"I love programming with Python-3 . 3 ! Do you ? It's great ... I give it a 10/10 . It's free-    to-use , no $$$ involved ! "
```

But the problem is that it does not separate sentences into new lines. How can I use a regex to do that before I create whitespace between punctuation and characters?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python - How do I separate punctuation from words by white space leaving only one space between the punctuation and the word?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810884/python-how-do-i-separate-punctuation-from-words-by-white-space-leaving-only-on)

Comment: @Joel, yes, but the difference is that I am trying to use a regex to first split the sentences and place each on a new line, and then use the second regex mentioned above to separate words and punctuation by whitespace.

Comment: So, how do you know that something is a new sentence?

Comment: By ".", "?" or "!". But there is a problem with the "." - for example, consider this paragraph:  Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't. What a great movie! I loved it. I loved it!!! Did you??? I did.!? Not really it was bad!
This can be solved by: "(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<![A-Z][a-z]\.)(?<=\.|\?|\!)\s"

Comment: So my question is basically before you go into the regular expressions, you need to decide what the rule is you're using.  In your sample input, punctuation followed by capital is enough.  In what you just gave it's not.  What I was trying to get with my question is, in English, what is the rule you want to impose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
([!?.])(?=\s*[A-Z])\s*
```

You can use this regex to create sentences before your regex.See demo.Replace by `\1\n`.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/5

```
x="I love programming with Python-3.3! Do you? It's great... I give it a 10/10. It's free-to-use, no $$$ involved!"
print re.sub(r"([!?.])(?=\s*[A-Z])",r"\1\n",x)
```

EDIT:

```
(?<![A-Z][a-z])([!?.])(?=\s*[A-Z])\s*
```

Try this.See demo for your different set of data.

https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/9

Comment: This works perfectly. But if I use the following string as the "TEST STRING": """Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't. What a great movie! I loved it. I loved it!!! Did you??? I did.!? Not really it was bad!"""                                                                 The result is good, but "Mr." is seen as a separate sentence. How can I fix this @vks ?

Comment: How can I combine the two regexes to work with both sets of sentences?? This regex can not see that "I love this movie!" is a separate sentence. Can you please help?

Comment: @modarwish what is the exact input

Comment: input = """Mr. Smith bought cheapsite.com for 1.5 million dollars, i.e. he paid a lot for it. Did he mind? Adam Jones Jr. thinks he didn't. In any case, this isn't true... Well, with a probability of .9 it isn't. What a great movie! I loved it. I loved it!!! Did you??? I did.!? Not really it was bad! I love this movie. It is great, but the actors suck. The sound affects are terrible . I love this movie. It is good. But the sound is bad. I love programming with Python-3.3! Do you? It's great... I give it a 10/10. It's free-to-use, no $$$ involved!""" I need to split them into a list.

Comment: @modarwish this is late, but you can try `nltk`'s machine learning-trained sentence splitter that deals with "Mr. " and things like that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
>>> import re
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> print re.sub(r'(?<=['+punctuation+'])\s+(?=[A-Z])', '\n', input)
I love programming with Python-3.3!
Do you?
It's great...
I give it a 10/10.
It's free-to-use, no $$$ involved!
```

Comment: How can this be used for unicode characters from language like hindi.i am facing similar issue for converting paragraph to lines

Comment: @gaurus If you know the unicode range, you can directly place it in character range instead of `[A-Z]`